# Logstash multiline filter - custom message

Tags: logstash, kibana

I need to add a cutom logstash filter to use it correctly with kibana. 
My custom logs are in this format:

```
[2015-03-06 16:00:06] Erroneous response from facebook
Invalid OAuth access token.
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 190
    }
}
[2015-03-06 16:00:06] Erroneous response from facebook
Invalid OAuth access token.
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 190
    }
}
```

For instance above I pasted two different messages.
What I have to do with my forwarder and logstash server to collect just one message and not one each line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you need a multiline filter.  Something like this might work:

```
filter {
    multiline {
      negate => 'true'
      pattern => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
      what => 'previous'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in this case is note a pattern to use, i'm trying to write some custom regexp

Comment: The examples you gave do not require a custom regexp, but you can put one in 'pattern' if it makes you happy.